# How to get object from JSON string and save to database with JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, api

Can anybody show me how to retrieve an object from JSON string. I'm stuck anh i really need help. For example i have an JSON string like this

```
 "traits": [
    {
      "trait_type": "type",
      "value": "Male",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 6039,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Mohawk",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 441,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Smile",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 238,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "2 attributes",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 3279,
      "order": null
    }
  ],
```

And i wanna get some object like this

```
 "traits": [
   {
       "trait_type": "type",
      "value": "Male",
   },

   {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Mohawk",
   },
   {
     "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Smile",
   },
   {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "2 attributes",
   },
],
```

I hope if anybody can help me or give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable that contains the JSON string you would use `JSON.parse();`

I assume that you have your JSON in a file.

If you need to mutate existing object you can try this:

```
const traits = require('./your_JSON.json');

traits.map(trait => {
  delete element.display_type;
  delete element.max_value;
  delete element.trait_count;
  delete element.order;
})
```

If you want to save your object and create a new array with new data, use for loop:

```
const newArr = [];

for(let trait of traits) {
 newArr.push({"trait_type": trait.trait_type, "value": trait.value});
}
```